# php form should not refresh after validation

Tags: php, html

This is a Form I want to validate. The form has a select menu and if I select an option from the dropdown  it shows two textboxes and an select menu. After submitting the form, the page refreshes and the form fields that I wanted to validate also hide.

What I want to do is validating the form without a page refresh.

**Edited please note this:** If i select other option that is IE,Safari except other option and submit the validation arise for that also

```
<html> 
<head>  
<style>
#browserother{display:none;}
.error
{
    color:#F00;
}
</style> 
<?php
$otherbrowser1="";
$otherbrowser1Err="";

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']== "POST") {
   $valid = true;
   if(empty($_POST["ob1"]))
    {
        $otherbrowser1Err="* otherbrowser1 is Required";
        $valid=false;
        echo "<style>#browserother{display:block;}</style>";
    }
    else
    {
        $otherbrowser1=test_input($_POST["ob1"]);
    }
    //if valid then redirect
  if($valid){
      include 'database.php';
      echo '<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" Content="0; URL=success.php">';    
    exit;
  }  
}

function test_input($data)
{
     $data = trim($data);
     $data = stripslashes($data);
     $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
     return $data;
}

?>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js">
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="jsform" method="post" action="<?php htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">
<p>Chose Your Browser: <select name = "Browser" required>
        <option value = "">-- Select an Option --</option>
        <option value = "1" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "1") echo "selected"; ?>>IE</option>
        <option value = "2" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "2") echo "selected"; ?>>FF</option>
        <option value = "3" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "3") echo "selected"; ?>>Safari</option>
        <option value = "4" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "4") echo "selected"; ?>>Opera</option>
        <option value = "5" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "5") echo "selected"; ?>>Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
  <div id="browserother">
    Please Specify: <label><input type="text" name="ob1" placeholder="Other Browser1" size="50" /></label>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $otherbrowser1Err?></span>
    <br>
       Please Specify: <label><input type="text" placeholder="Other Browser2" size="50" /></label><br>
 Please Specify: <label>
 <select>
 <option>Select an Option</option>
  <option>Select an Option</option>
 </select>
 </label>
    </div>

  <!--currentstatus starts here-->
<script type="text/javascript">

$('p select[name=Browser]').change(function(e){
  if ($('p select[name=Browser]').val() == '5'){
    $('#browserother').show();
  }else{
    $('#browserother').hide();
  }
});

$('p select[name=OS]').change(function(){
  if ($('p select[name=OS]').val() == 'otheros'){
    $('#osother').show();
  }else{
    $('#osother').hide();
  }
});
</script>
  <!--currentstatus Ends here-->
   <input type="button" value = "Submit" onClick=" document.getElementById('jsform').submit();" />
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please rephrase your question.

Comment: php forms will refresh after validation,use ajax for this purpose

Comment: If you want to stop form from being refreshed after validation, use return false; so everything stops right there without proceeding any further.

Comment: If you want us to help you, please show some effort and a minimal understanding of the problem. Just posting some random code is not what we're expecting when we want the asker to provide code...

Comment: @ArunKumar try the above code and u will come to known what's the problem in code

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat please try the above code and u will come to know what is my problem friend

Comment: @ArunKumar i don't want to hide #browserother after submit because i have validation inside #browserother

Comment: @ThomasDavidPlat i don't want to hide #browserother after submit because i have validation inside #browserother

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's difficult to understand what is the exact question.

Anyway I believe that you you don't want `#browserother` to be hidden in case of error ?
if so make sure that when you validate the form, add a display block for: `#browserother`

```
if(empty($_POST["ob1"]))
{
    $otherbrowser1Err="* otherbrowser1 is Required";
    $valid=false;
    echo "<style>#browserother{display:block;}</style>";
}
```

Anyway very ugly code.

for dropdown:

```
<p>Chose Your Browser: <select name = "Browser" required>
        <option value = "">-- Select an Option --</option>
        <option value = "1" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "1") echo "selected"; ?>>IE</option>
        <option value = "2" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "2") echo "selected"; ?>>FF</option>
        <option value = "3" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "3") echo "selected"; ?>>Safari</option>
        <option value = "4" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "4") echo "selected"; ?>>Opera</option>
        <option value = "5" <?php if(isset($_POST["Browser"]) && $_POST["Browser"] == "5") echo "selected"; ?>>Other</option>
        </select>
    </p>
```

I don't see any code for other cases, but to validate that field only when last option selected you should replace your code with this:

```
if ($_POST['Browser'] == 5) {
        if(empty($_POST["ob1"]))
        {
            $otherbrowser1Err="* otherbrowser1 is Required";
            $valid=false;
            echo "<style>#browserother{display:block;}</style>";
        }
        else
        {
            $otherbrowser1=test_input($_POST["ob1"]);
        }
}
```

which means to ask for validation of ob1 field only when last value is selected.

Comment: C U exactly correct i don't want to hide #browserother after validation

Comment: @Geetha why dont you do validation in jquery as i said, it will not refesh ur page if any validation fails, all data will be as it was before

Comment: @Marius.C ur code help me but why my dropdown option get (Employed)refreshed

Comment: updated the post. should work now I believe. you have to check the $_POST with the `value` from the input not with html

Comment: @Marius.C i have one more problem if i select other option that is IE and submit the form then also the validation arise its not submitting the form. help me friend

Answer (score 2):

PHP basically refresh the page,You could use the [submitHandler option](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options). Basically put the $.ajax call inside this handler, i.e. invert it with the validation setup logic.
you can use some code like this :

```
  $('#form').validate(function(){

        ... your validation rules come here,

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $.ajax({
                url: form.action,
                type: form.method,
                data: $(form).serialize(),
                success: function(response) {
                    $('#answers').html(response);
                }            
            });
        }
       return false;
    });
```

and in your html

```
<form id="jsform" method="post" action="">
```

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to check validation before submission of form and after validating all fields you wish to submit form, then instead "onclick" event of button, write a submit event of form or click event of button.

Inside that event check validation and then submit your form. If any field is invalid then return it from there only.

Answer (score 0):

PHP form will refresh once you click submit button.So please do validation in javascript or jquery and after that use php for getting form values.

Remove onclick from submit button and add id and name attr to it

```
$("#submitbuttonid").click(function(e){

if($('input[name^=ob1]').val() == "")
{
  alert("Other browser is req.");  
 return false;
}

});
```

Comment: @downvoter can you plz explain me whats wrong with this answer ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon submitting the form the page refreshes, either use AJAX as said above or in your inputs that you want to be saved type

```
<input type="text" name="whatever_name" value="<?php if (isset($_POST['whatever_name'])) echo $_POST['whatever_name'];?>" />
```

This way when you submit the data that was submited will be in the form "value" attributes.

But I would advise using ajax, as it's more clean.

Answer (score 0):

Your code was pretty cluttered I don't even know where to begin. Your validation had logical flaws, you were mixing HTML and PHP kinda strangely and so on. I felt free to rewrite it a little bit and I added the feature you asked for.

Normally I don't do this but I want to show you a cleaner way to do such kind of tasks for the future. Of course this isn't the ideal way either (stuffing evertything into a single file is not the best practice as you may know).

For your understanding I commented everything. But basically we are sending an ajax request to the script. The script validates  our form and returns a json response. This is a neat way to manage data between client and server.

The redirection process then takes place on the client side and redirects the user if everything was okay.

**Please note that I did not do any security checks here**

```
<?php

// Just a helper function to check if a form field is set and filled
function fieldSet($field)
{
    return isset($field) AND !empty($field);
}

// Our dropdown will be generated from that array
$browsers = array('IE', 'FF', 'Safari', 'Opera', 'Other');

/**
 * Lets process this when a POST Request came in
 */

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST')
{   
    // Set JSON Header
    header('Content-Type: application/json');

    // Prepare our response
    $response = array('success' => false);

    // Reassign POST variables just to make it look prettier
    $browser_select = $_POST['browser'];
    $specifications = $_POST['specify'];

    // If a browser has not been selected the user failed hard!
    if(!fieldSet($browser_select) OR $browser_select == 'init')
        $response['errors'][] = 'Please Select a browser';

    // If we selected 'other' check if the hidden form group has any input 
    // and push an error to our $response array if not
    if($browser_select == $browsers[4] AND (!fieldSet($specifications) OR $specifications[2] == 'init'))
        $response['errors'][] = 'Another Browser is required';

    // If we got no errors in our $response array the request was successful
    if(!isset($response['errors']))
        $response['success'] = true;

    // Encode our $response array into the JSON format and 
    // abort script execution
    echo json_encode($response);
    exit;


}


?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>My Ajax Form</title>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
    </head>

    <body>
        <form action="cleanform.php" method="POST" id="ajax-form">
            <label for="select-browser">Choose your Browser</label>
            <option value="init">Please select a browser</option>               
            <select name="browser" id="select-browser">
                <?php foreach($browsers AS $browser): ?>
                    <option value="<?php echo $browser; ?>"><?php echo $browser; ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
            <hr>
            <div id="hidden-field-group" style="display: none;">
                <label for="specify-1">Please Specify</label>
                <input type="text" name="specify[]" placeholder="Other Browser 1" id="specify-1">
                <br>
                <label for="specify-2">Please Specify</label>
                <input type="text" name="specify[]" placeholder="Other Browser 2" id="specify-2">
                <br>
                <label for="specification-3">Please Specify</label>
                <select name="specify[]" id="specify-3">
                    <option value="init">Please Specify</option>
                    <option value="SP 1">SP1</option>
                    <option value="SP 2">SP2</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <input type="submit">

        </form>


        <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            var $form = $('#ajax-form');
            var $browserSelect = $form.find('select[name="browser"]');

            // Hide or Show the second form group
            $browserSelect.on('change', function(){
                $select = $(this);
                if($select.val() == 'Other'){
                    $('#hidden-field-group').show();
                }
                else{
                    $('#hidden-field-group').hide();
                }
            });

            // Here we send a POST Request to the server using AJAX
            $form.on('submit', function(e){
                // Prevent the browser from submitting the form
                // in it's native way
                e.preventDefault();
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: $form.action,
                    data: $form.serialize(), //Serialize our form fields
                    success: function(response)
                    {   
                        // Redirect if the server returned no error
                        if(response.success == true)
                            window.location.replace("http://example.com");
                        //otherwise print the error
                        else
                            alert(response.errors[0]);
                    }

                });
            });

        });

        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```